# resolv.conf does not work as expected

Tags: networking, dns, resolv.conf, resolvconf

As you can see [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/resolv.conf.5.html) (and in `man resolv.conf`), there is an option named `use-vc` for `resolv.conf` to force Ubuntu to use TCP for DNS queries instead of UDP.

> **use-vc (since glibc 2.14)**
>
> Sets RES_USEVC in _res.options.  This option
>   forces the use of  TCP  for  DNS resolutions.

This option doesn't work for me.

My Ubuntu:

```
ebrahim@ebrahim:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.10
Release:    16.10
Codename:   yakkety

ebrahim@ebrahim:~$ uname -a
Linux ebrahim 4.8.0-58-generic #63-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 26 17:08:21 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

ebrahim@ebrahim:~$ ldd --version
ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.24-3ubuntu2.2) 2.24
```

As you see above, my `glibc` is newer version than the required version in the resolv.conf manual page.

This is my configuration file:

```
ebrahim@ebrahim:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
options use-vc
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

But still DNS queries are on UDP:[image]

Why?

(Note that I have tried this option on 6 different Ubuntu OS, 3 of them was okay and 3 doesn't worked!)

Comment: did you even restart the `networking` service after making changes? Also, editing `/etc/resolv.conf` directly is the wrong way to make changes. Add additional settings to `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` instead.

Comment: As far as I know, restart is not required for `/etc/resolv.conf` changes (It was not required for those three Ubuntu which worked fine). Actually restart will rewrite this file! Anyway I  add this option in the `/etc/network/interfaces` and in the `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head`, and then I restarted networking service, but nothing changed.

Comment: I was just letting you know the proper way to make changes. Why do you want to use TCP anyway?

Comment: @xR34P3Rx I want to disable UDP DNS traffic in my network to mitigate Reflected DNS Flood attack to my network.

Comment: What Ubuntu versions did you try? Which worked, which didn't? Please [add](https://askubuntu.com/posts/959107/edit) all information to your question rather than using comments!

Comment: Ubuntu 16.10  is no longer supported as of [July 20 of 2017.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release might be useful for you.